# SDL2 Camera Cutting Off Screen Edges

Tags: c, camera, sdl-2

I'm trying to create a simple camera for my SDL2 platformer with C. However, whenever the player reaches the screen edges, it seems to be cut off by the background. Here is what the player looks like normally:
[image]

And here is what the player looks like when it reaches the screen edges:

[image]

To make the camera follow the player, I'm just creating a SDL_Rect called camera, setting it to the player x and y positions, and setting the viewport with `SDL_RenderSetViewport` to the camera rectangle.

Here's the code for that:

```c
void handle_camera() {
    SDL_Rect camera = {
        .x = WIDTH/2 - player.x - BLOCK_SIZE/2,
        .y = HEIGHT/2 - player.y - BLOCK_SIZE/2,
        .w = WIDTH,
        .h = HEIGHT
    };
    SDL_RenderSetViewport(game.renderer, &camera);   
}
```

Therefore, I was wondering: what's wrong with my camera function and why is the player being cut off when it gets near the screen edges?

Here is the full code if needed (I organized in functions so I hope it's not too hard to understand):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

#define WIDTH 1200
#define HEIGHT 800
#define BLOCK_SIZE 50
#define PLATFORM_AMOUNT 11 //This makes sure there are enough iterations of the loop, and also allocates enough memory for the 2D array of platforms.
#define LAVA_AMOUNT 2
#define TRAMPOLINE_AMOUNT 1


//Prototyping Functions
int initialize();
void handle_input(); 
void draw_player();
void player_moveX();
void player_moveY();
void checkCollisionsX();
void checkCollisionsY();
int rectCollide();
void drawLevel();
void resetPlayer();
void handle_camera();

typedef struct {
    SDL_Renderer *renderer;
    SDL_Window *window;
    SDL_Surface *surface;
    bool running;
    int FPS;
    bool close_requested;
    int input[256];
} Game;

Game game = {
  .running = true,
  .FPS = 80,
  .close_requested = false,
  .input = {},
};

typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
    double x_vel;
    double y_vel;
    double x_acc;
    double y_acc;
    int width;
    int height;

    double accSpeed;
    int maxVel;
    double gravity;
    double friction;
    double jumpForce;
    double canJump;
} Player;

Player player = {
    .y = HEIGHT-(BLOCK_SIZE*2),
    .x = BLOCK_SIZE,
    .x_vel = 0,
    .y_vel = 0,
    .x_acc = 0,
    .y_acc = 0,
    .width = BLOCK_SIZE,
    .height = BLOCK_SIZE,

    .accSpeed = 0.15,
    .maxVel = 7,
    .gravity = 0.5,
    .friction = 0.15,
    .jumpForce = 15,
    .canJump = true,
};

int platforms[PLATFORM_AMOUNT][4] = {

    {0, 0, BLOCK_SIZE, HEIGHT}, //WALLS
    {0, HEIGHT-BLOCK_SIZE, WIDTH, BLOCK_SIZE},

    {400-BLOCK_SIZE, HEIGHT-(BLOCK_SIZE*2), BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE}, //RAMP TO LAVA
    {400-BLOCK_SIZE, HEIGHT-(BLOCK_SIZE*3), BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE},
    {300, HEIGHT-(BLOCK_SIZE*2), BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE},
    {800, HEIGHT-(BLOCK_SIZE*2), BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE},
    {800, HEIGHT-(BLOCK_SIZE*3), BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE},
    {800+BLOCK_SIZE, HEIGHT-(BLOCK_SIZE*2), BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE},

    {WIDTH-BLOCK_SIZE*10, HEIGHT-(BLOCK_SIZE*8), BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE}, //Blocks above lava
    {WIDTH-BLOCK_SIZE*8, HEIGHT-(BLOCK_SIZE*10), BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE},

    {BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE*3, BLOCK_SIZE*9, BLOCK_SIZE}, //Top platform

};

int lava[LAVA_AMOUNT][4] = {
    {400, HEIGHT-(BLOCK_SIZE*3), 400, BLOCK_SIZE*2},
    {BLOCK_SIZE*4, BLOCK_SIZE*2, BLOCK_SIZE*3, BLOCK_SIZE},
};

int trampoline[TRAMPOLINE_AMOUNT][4] = {
    {WIDTH/2-(BLOCK_SIZE/2), HEIGHT-(BLOCK_SIZE*5), BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE}
};

int main() {

    initialize();

    while(game.running && !game.close_requested) { //Game loop

        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(game.renderer, 181, 247, 255, 255);
        SDL_RenderClear(game.renderer);

        handle_input();
        handle_camera();

        //Collisions only work in this order: playerMoveX, checkCollisionsX, playerMoveY, checkCollisionsY. Then you can draw the platforms and the player.

        player_moveX();
        checkCollisionsX();
        player_moveY();
        checkCollisionsY();

        drawLevel();
        draw_player();

        SDL_RenderPresent(game.renderer);
        SDL_Delay(1000/game.FPS);

    } //End of game loop

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(game.renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(game.window);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}

int initialize() {

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO|SDL_INIT_TIMER) != 0) { //return 0 on success
        printf("error initializing SDL: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

    game.window = SDL_CreateWindow("Sam's Platformer", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, WIDTH, HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE); //creates window
    if (!game.window) {
        printf("error creating window: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        SDL_Quit();
        return 1;
    }

    Uint32 render_flags = SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC; //creates a renderer
    game.renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(game.window, -1, render_flags);
    if (!game.renderer) {
        printf("error creating renderer: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        SDL_DestroyWindow(game.window);
        SDL_Quit();
        return 1;
    }

  return 0;
}

void handle_input() {

    SDL_Event event;

    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
        if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
            game.close_requested = true;
            game.running = false;
        }

        //printf("input: %p code: %i\n", game.input, event.key.keysym.scancode);
        if (event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN) {
            game.input[event.key.keysym.scancode] = true;
            //printf("True");
        }
        if (event.type == SDL_KEYUP) {
            game.input[event.key.keysym.scancode] = false;
            //printf("False");
        }
    }

    if (game.input[SDL_SCANCODE_R]) {
        resetPlayer();
    }
}

void draw_player() {
    SDL_Rect playerRect = {
        .x = player.x,
        .y = player.y,
        .w = player.width,
        .h = player.height
    };

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(game.renderer, 0, 200, 50, 255);
    SDL_RenderFillRect(game.renderer, &playerRect);
}

void resetPlayer() {
    player.y = HEIGHT-(BLOCK_SIZE*2);
    player.x = BLOCK_SIZE;
    player.x_vel = 0;
    player.y_vel = 0;
}

void player_moveX() {
    if (game.input[SDL_SCANCODE_LEFT] && player.x_vel > -player.maxVel) {
        player.x_acc = -player.accSpeed;
    } else if (game.input[SDL_SCANCODE_RIGHT] && player.x_vel < player.maxVel) {
        player.x_acc = player.accSpeed;
    } else if (abs(player.x_vel) > 0.2) {
        if (player.x_vel < 0) {
            player.x_acc = player.friction;
        } else {
            player.x_acc = -player.friction;
        }
    } else {
        player.x_vel = 0;
        player.x_acc = 0;
    }
    player.x_vel += player.x_acc;
    player.x += player.x_vel;
}

void player_moveY() {
    if (game.input[SDL_SCANCODE_UP] && player.y_vel == 0 && player.y_acc == 0 && player.canJump) {
        player.canJump = false;
        player.y_vel = -player.jumpForce;
    }
    player.y_acc += player.gravity;
    player.y_vel += player.y_acc;
    player.y += player.y_vel;
    player.y_acc = 0;
}

void checkCollisionsX() {
    for (int i = 0; i < PLATFORM_AMOUNT; i++) {
        if (rectCollide(player.x, player.y, BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE, platforms[i][0], platforms[i][1], platforms[i][2], platforms[i][3])) {
            if (player.x_vel < 0) { // If the player moved left and collided with the right side of block
                player.x = platforms[i][0] + platforms[i][2];
            } else { // If the player moved right and collided with the left side of block
                player.x = platforms[i][0] - player.width;
            }
            player.x_vel = 0;
        }
    }
    /*if (player.x >= WIDTH - player.width) {
        player.x = WIDTH - player.width;
        player.x_vel = 0;
    }*/
    for (int i = 0; i < LAVA_AMOUNT; i++) {
        if (rectCollide(player.x, player.y, BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE, lava[i][0], lava[i][1], lava[i][2], lava[i][3])) {
            resetPlayer();
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < TRAMPOLINE_AMOUNT; i++) {
        if (rectCollide(player.x, player.y, BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE, trampoline[i][0], trampoline[i][1], trampoline[i][2], trampoline[i][3])) {
            if (player.x_vel < 0) { // If the player moved left and collided with the right side of block
                player.x = trampoline[i][0] + trampoline[i][2];
            } else { // If the player moved right and collided with the left side of block
                player.x = trampoline[i][0] - player.width;
            }
            player.x_vel = 0;
        }
    }
}

void checkCollisionsY() {
    for (int i = 0; i < PLATFORM_AMOUNT; i++) {
        if (rectCollide(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height, platforms[i][0], platforms[i][1], platforms[i][2], platforms[i][3])) {
            if (player.y_vel < 0) { // If the player hit their head
                player.y = platforms[i][1] + platforms[i][3];
                player.y_vel *= -0.5; // Not -1 because collisions are not perfectly elastic
            } else {
                player.y = platforms[i][1] - player.height;
                player.y_vel = 0;
                player.y_acc = 0;
                player.canJump = true;
            }
        }
        if (player.y >= HEIGHT - player.height) {
            player.y_vel = 0;
            player.y = HEIGHT - player.height;
            if (!game.input[SDL_SCANCODE_UP]) {
                player.canJump = true;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < LAVA_AMOUNT; i++) {
        if (rectCollide(player.x, player.y, BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE, lava[i][0], lava[i][1], lava[i][2], lava[i][3])) {
            resetPlayer();
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < TRAMPOLINE_AMOUNT; i++) {
        if (rectCollide(player.x, player.y, BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE, trampoline[i][0], trampoline[i][1], trampoline[i][2], trampoline[i][3])) {
            if (player.y_vel < 0) { // If the player hit their head
                player.y = trampoline[i][1] + trampoline[i][3];
                player.y_vel *= -0.5; // Not -1 because collisions are not perfectly elastic
            } else {
                player.y = trampoline[i][1] - trampoline[i][3];
                player.y_vel = -player.y_vel;
            }
        }
    }
}

int rectCollide(int x1, int y1, int w1, int h1, int x2,int y2, int w2, int h2) {
  return x1 + w1 > x2 && x1 < x2 + w2 && y1 + h1 > y2 && y1 < y2 + h2;
}

void drawLevel() {
    for (int i = 0; i < PLATFORM_AMOUNT; i++) {
        SDL_Rect platform = {platforms[i][0], platforms[i][1], platforms[i][2], platforms[i][3]};
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(game.renderer, 156, 104, 0, 255);
        SDL_RenderFillRect(game.renderer, &platform);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < LAVA_AMOUNT; i++) {
        int lavaRedColor = 255;
        SDL_Rect lavaBlock = {lava[i][0], lava[i][1], lava[i][2], lava[i][3]};
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(game.renderer, lavaRedColor, 0, 0, 255);
        SDL_RenderFillRect(game.renderer, &lavaBlock);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < TRAMPOLINE_AMOUNT; i++) {
        SDL_Rect trampolineBlock = {trampoline[i][0], trampoline[i][1], trampoline[i][2], trampoline[i][3]};
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(game.renderer, 235, 52, 229, 255);
        SDL_RenderFillRect(game.renderer, &trampolineBlock);
    }
}

void handle_camera() {
    SDL_Rect camera = {
        .x = WIDTH/2 - player.x - BLOCK_SIZE/2,
        .y = HEIGHT/2 - player.y - BLOCK_SIZE/2,
        .w = WIDTH, //Screen width
        .h = HEIGHT //Screen height
    };
    SDL_RenderSetViewport(game.renderer, &camera);   
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/121421/how-to-use-the-sdl-viewport-properly

See this related post. Essentially changing the SDL viewport is not the way you'd typically handle an in game camera. You need to consider drawing your in game entities (level objects etc.) relative to the camera.